# Managing additional hardware in Android

Tags: android, workflow, driver, linux-device-driver, device

What should I add/modify in order to make Android manage additional devices attached to the AMBA bus?

What I want to realize is to trigger a certain action (described in my Android app) when the new component generates an hardware interrupt.

I have already a working Linux device Driver but I don't know how to extend the rest of the Android stack (HAL, Android Services, Binder etc...)

EDIT:
I've been referred to chapter "Adding Support for New Hardware" of "Embedded Android". It is very useful and full of advices. My question remains unanswered

Comment: The answer will depend on what kind of device this is.

Comment: I'm currently handling a AES-crypto engine attached to the AMBA bus. It takes the plaintext into one register and the key into another. When the encryption is finished, the result is putted into the third register and then it generates an hardware interrupt.

Comment: For now, you may have to implement your own .so and create your own API into the kernel for this type of encryption.  The existing crypto interface seems to be software-based or built around ARM TrustZone.

Comment: "The existing crypto interface seems to be software-based or built around ARM TrustZone"
it is generated by me in VHDL

Comment: I meant that the interface in Android does not seem to consider this type of implementation.

Comment: so, except the kernel driver, which resource should i add/modify?